# Can't detect serial port on "El Capitan" OSX

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-ide

My Arduino Micro Atmega32u4 was working fine until I got fed up of apple reminding me to update, under those updates there was a security setting that I believe is the cause behind of all this. Now when I try to program my arduino the IDE does not recognize the port. I only get /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port which doesn't let me program it. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? I'm running OSX EL capitan 10.11.6 & the Arduino version is 1.6.12. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to use my linux machine because my Mac OSX running 10.11.6 El Capitan was not recognizing the arduino micro but on the Linux machine it would at least pick up signal for 7 seconds. So you have to "not have the micro plugged into a usb port. Have the arduino ide open with a simple bare minimum sketch, select the leonardo board (yes even if your using a micro). Press the reset button on your micro and hold, continue holding, and plug your board into a usb port. Continue holding the reset button and select upload the sketch. As soon as your ide window finishes compiling the sketch and begins the upload process release the reset button.

My final results: The sketch loaded and the port dropping connection got fixed, my micro was continued to be recognized by the IDE program even on El Capitan. This was caused because I uploaded a sketch that was too big the arduino micro to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is an China Arduino clone with a CH340/1 USB serial chipset; the drivers were not signed previously and new MacOS versions do not allow unsigned kernel drivers (ktext).

Try installing the new signed drivers linked here: https://blog.sengotta.net/signed-mac-os-driver-for-winchiphead-ch340-serial-bridge/

Comment: it's not a clone and the chipset is ATMega324u4 but I managed to fix it. Thanks.